# buffer.js throws Unknown encoding: base64url

Tags: javascript, buffer, base64url

the line

```
publicKey = Buffer.from(publicKey, 'base64url');
```

throws

```
uncaughtException server.js TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: base64url
    at fromString (buffer.js:451:13)
    at Function.from (buffer.js:305:12)
    at Object.validatePublicKey (C:\Users\libor\OneDrive\Escritorio\todo\dev\Aplay\proyectos\cms-mimediodetest3\node_modules\web-push\src\vapid-helper.js:107:22)
```

I'm using node:12.22.12 and buffer:3.6.4
I have searched for fixes and found nothing
I have searched in the docs and [buffer accepts base64url](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding:%7E:text=%27base64url%27%3A%20base64url%20encoding%20as%20specified%20in%20RFC%204648%2C%20Section%205.%20When%20creating%20a%20Buffer%20from%20a%20string%2C%20this%20encoding%20will%20also%20correctly%20accept%20regular%20base64%2Dencoded%20strings.%20When%20encoding%20a%20Buffer%20to%20a%20string%2C%20this%20encoding%20will%20omit%20padding.)
I have no idea what to do

Comment: I think you have mentioned the wrong encoding. Should be 'base64' instead of 'base64url'

Comment: @Vaulstein  It is intentional, it even is contemplated in the buffer docs, the code with the error isn't mine tho, is from a module, but the error itself doesn't make sense given all this things